# Add specific Facebook Like Button for comments posted by inline ajax comments (WP plugin)

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, wordpress

The facebook famous `div="fb-like"` don't open into every comments, outside yes ! I put it into the template of the inline ajax comments (WP plugin) like that :

```
function inline_comments_load_template(){

check_ajax_referer('inline_comments_nonce', 'security');

    $comments = get_comments( array(
        'post_id' => (int)$_POST['post_id'],
        'number'  => 100,
        'status'  => 'approve',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ) );

    ?>
    <div class="inline-comments-container" id="comments_target">
        <?php if ( $comments ) : foreach( $comments as $comment) : ?>
            <?php
            $user = new WP_User( $comment->user_id );
            $class = null;
            if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
                foreach ( $user->roles as $role ){
                    $class = $role;
                }
            } else {
                $class = 'annon';
            }
            ?>
            <div class="inline-comments-content inline-comments-<?php echo $class; ?>" id="comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>">
                <div class="inline-comments-p">
                    <?php inline_comments_profile_pic( $comment->comment_author_email ); ?>
                    <?php print $comment->comment_content; ?><br />

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://YOUR-URL/#<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

                    <time class="meta">
                        <strong><?php $user = get_user_by('login', $comment->comment_author ); if ( ! empty( $user->user_url ) ) : ?><a href="<?php print $user->user_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php print $comment->comment_author; ?></a><?php else : ?><?php print $comment->comment_author; ?><?php endif; ?></strong>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID); ?>#<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" class="inline-comments-time-handle" data-comment_id="<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>"><?php print human_time_diff( strtotime( $comment->comment_date ), current_time('timestamp') ); ?> ago.</a>
                    </time>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php die();
}
```

I think that it not necessary to change other files of the plugin, just this function concern the html code... Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It necessary to include Facebook script inside this function like that :

```
function inline_comments_load_template(){

    check_ajax_referer('inline_comments_nonce', 'security');

    $comments = get_comments( array(
        'post_id' => (int)$_POST['post_id'],
        'number'  => 100,
        'status'  => 'approve',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ) );

    ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="inline-comments-container" id="comments_target">
        <?php if ( $comments ) : foreach( $comments as $comment) : ?>
            <?php
            $user = new WP_User( $comment->user_id );
            $class = null;
            if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
                foreach ( $user->roles as $role ){
                    $class = $role;
                }
            } else {
                $class = 'annon';
            }
            ?>
            <div class="inline-comments-content inline-comments-<?php echo $class; ?>" id="comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>">
                <div class="inline-comments-p">
                    <?php inline_comments_profile_pic( $comment->comment_author_email ); ?>
                    <?php print $comment->comment_content; ?><br />

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://YOUR-URL#<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

                    <time class="meta">
                        <strong><?php $user = get_user_by('login', $comment->comment_author ); if ( ! empty( $user->user_url ) ) : ?><a href="<?php print $user->user_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php print $comment->comment_author; ?></a><?php else : ?><?php print $comment->comment_author; ?><?php endif; ?></strong>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID); ?>#<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" class="inline-comments-time-handle" data-comment_id="<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>"><?php print human_time_diff( strtotime( $comment->comment_date ), current_time('timestamp') ); ?> ago.</a>
                    </time>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php die();
}
```